# Accessing friend list in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to access the friend list of a facebook user without getting his explicit permission ?

For example, my friend's friend list is public. Anyone with a facebook profile can see who his friends are. Given his id, do I need explicit permission from him to iterate through his friend list ?

Comment: You cannot mine peoples lists without gaining permission via their api. Even trying to scrape it will cause you great pain and suffering.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Graph API method:

https://graph.facebook.com/{user}/friends

but you need an additional access token from the user

***from the API docs*** - 
Getting an access token for a user with no extended permissions allows you to access the information that the user has made available to everyone on Facebook.

there are two other methods that I know of

See this for the FQL: 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friendlist/

Depreciated call, Get method: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/friends.getLists/

As far as permissions note this

**Friend lists are private on Facebook, so you cannot republish this information to anyone other than the logged in user.**

Answer (score 0):

but easily you can get the friends work and education details.. just run this query in Graph API Eplorer

```
SELECT flid, owner, name FROM friendlist WHERE owner=me()
```