# Trouble Accessing Facebook Friends without Login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to understand how Airbnb is able to access Facebook Friend lists without an active Facebook logged in session. To see this in action follow this link:

https://www.airbnb.com/s/Austin?neighborhoods[]=Barton+Hills

Once there, select a listing and midway down the page you will find a "Friends" tab. Assuming the property owner has some Facebook friends, you should see the friend photos and when you hover over them, you will get a message "xxxxxxxx is a Facebook friend of xxxxxxx". Where the "xxxxxxx" are replaced with the friend's name and the property owner's name.

I've googled and yahood for an answer and found this on stackoverflow:

[Accessing friend list in facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015048/accessing-friend-list-in-facebook)

and this:

[Facebook PHP SDK: get people in network and friends of friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912699/facebook-php-sdk-get-people-in-network-and-friends-of-friends)

Neither of which is the solution I see on the Airbnb website. My thoughts are that Airbnb has some kind of special permission with Facebook to get this data or when property owners login using their personal Facebook info, Airbnb grabs the Friend data and stores it locally on their systems. Then they might update this every so often.

So, long story short, how does one get friend information on a public website about a Facebook member? Assuming you have a Facebook AppID and AppSecret.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without the user logging in and authorizing the application to access his details and then possibly storing the id's of his of her friends.

The problem with that is is does not update when the user adds more friends, or existing friends join the site too.